# Flutter - only few details in error messages

Tags: flutter, error-messaging

recently, I only get very undetailed error messages while developing with flutter. Here is an example:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

This is quiet annoying, as there is not even a line numer I can look at.
Would be great if somebody could help me, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It might be pointing to a variable field, or say an image or text file that you have deleted, but still accessing. Remove the code that points to the same, and the error could be resolved